# HTML too long scroll bars

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have got a little problem, if you look at my website you can see the scroll bars going down even though the page/content is only a couple of lines, if you check the page "CRS" or "Clients" then there should only be "test" and the scroll bar is still as long, anyone know how I could fix this problem?

http://mintystudios.co.uk/clients/naghmeh/

Comment: @Verandaguy - Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: because it has to do with HTML and CSS I thought, forgive me!

Comment: Yes, this is HTML. Also tagged as JavaScript, as you appear to be using a script-based scrollbar.

Comment: Technically, it's got to do with CSS, and not HTML.

Comment: @Verandaguy - CSS operates on HTML, so in essence every CSS question is also an HTML question.

Comment: Fair enough, but CSS should also be a tag for CSS and JavaScrip/JS on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `min-height` set on the divs with the class `slide` are being overridden by other styles set as `!important`. Taking `!important` off all the `min-height` styles in your CSS fixes the problem.

Alternatively, if that would break other parts of your site, make sure the `min-height` on the div is set as `!important` as well.

Answer (score 5):

There is a min-height set on the div:

```
<div id="CSR-in" class="slide" style="min-height: 598px; width: 958px;">
    test
    </div>
```

Comment: This `min-height` appears to be correct for what the OP wanted. The problem is that it is being overridden by other styles.